# Pricing an American call under the CGMY model

Tags: american-options

I am pricing an American call under the [CGMY model](http://engineering.nyu.edu/files/jbarticle.pdf) ($0 < Y < 1$) with strike $K$ at grid point $(x_i,\tau_j)$ where $x_i=x_{min}+i\,\Delta x $ for $i=0,1,...N$ and $\Delta x=\frac{x_{max}-x_{min}}{N}$.Why in the region $y\in(x_N-x_i,\infty)$ we have

\begin{align}
\int_{x_N-x_i}^{\infty}(w(x_i+y,\tau_j)-w(x_i,\tau_j))\frac{exp(-\lambda_p) y}{\nu(x_i,\tau_j)\, y^{1+Y}}\,\,dy=0
\end{align}

Where $w(x_i,\tau_j)$ is the premium at $(x_i,\tau_j)$.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @ emcor Why $\int_{x_N-x_i}^{\infty}(w(x_i+y,\tau_j)-w(x_i,\tau_j))\frac{exp(-\lambda_p) y}{\nu(x_i,\tau_i)\, y^{1+Y}}\,\,dy=0$?

Comment: Are you saying there are multiple strikes for each $x_i..._N$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$w$ is the premium"?

Comment: @ emcor  $K$ is fixed at each $(x_i,\tau_i)$

Comment: @ emco yes $w(x_i,\tau_i)$ is the premium

Comment: I assume $\tau$ is time to maturity? Is $w$ the option price or intrinsic/time value? Can you give the literature source?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: Any reference for your question? It is hard to know the background and the notations etc.

Comment: It looks like a condition so that the integral beyond the grid points is set to zero.